# Locating current Google Place i'm at by latitude/longitude via Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

i have a lat/long location data and i need to get current Google Place where i'm at now. 
**For example, if i'm in a shop(cafe, gym, etc..), i need to get info about THAT particular shop(cafe, gym, etc..).Or at least the closest one.**

So, i'm doing it this way:

First i fetch place basic info(placeid,name, etc.) via Google Places API Nearby Search request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.7597351,-73.9836576&radius=16.66&key=...
```

Then i find the closest one(which is apparently where i am) and perform Place Details request with it's **`placeid`**

So, everything works fine, except for some places like the one located at **40.7597351,-73.983657** (New York Guitar lab shop) which i **can see on google map**, but **can't get in my response**. Even places that are further from my location than this, are being found fine.

I've already tried to use **`rankBy=distance`** and then checking if the result is in required radius manually, still no use. Actually, maybe this approach is right, but as told in the docs, it's required to use **`types`** parameter with **`rankBy=distance`**. So, i set **`types=establishment`** since i actually need everything except addresses and locality tokens returned. I think that the problem is some places i need, are neither counted as establishments nor as localities, but i don't know the optimal way to exclude 
all types specified at (**https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types**) Table 2 from my response. Is there a way to get only places which types are in Table 1 (except for specifying them ALL in my **`types`** param, haha)

So, could you please help me with how can i do this?

Thanks:)

P.S. here is very similar but unaswered question 
[Google Places API Displaying Inaccurate Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312675/google-places-api-displaying-inaccurate-result?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's explanation here (https://developers.google.com/places/faq#why_are_some_places_never_returned_even_though_they_have_google_pages). Looks like some places are just not yet verified by Google.

And yes, the **establishment** is the generic category for all non-localities. So you can be sure that if you set `type=establishment` then you'll have as much places as you will, if you'll specify all types from Table 2. Good Luck!